# socket.io -- how to validate user input with server

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am trying to prompt user for input on the client, then check if the input is valid on the server. If the input is invalid the client should re-prompt until it receives a valid input.
Only once the input is valid should anything else proceed.

client.js

```
while(looping){
    temp_name = prompt(usr + err_msg + pmsg, "");
    socket.emit("is_valid", temp_name, (response) => {
        looping = !response.status
        err_msg = response.message
    });
}
```

server.js

```
// check if username is valid
    socket.on("is_valid", (temp_name, callback) => {
        // init
        let msg = "";
        let stat = false;

        // (check if valid)

        // return
        stat = (msg == "")
        response = {
            status: stat,
            message: msg,
        }
        callback(response);
    });
```

My code works if I remove the while loop in client.js.
But if I add the while loop, nothing works. No log statements print either.

The while loop is there because I want to prompt the user again if the input is invalid.

Why is this happening?

Thank you.

I expect it to return whether the temp_name is valid.

If it is valid, looping = false and it should exit the while loop.
If it is invalid, looping = true and it will prompt the user again. Currently all it does it repeatedly prompt the user no matter what is entered. But if I remove the while loop, it works correctly and returns the values I expect.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. The solution is to use a promise (on client, use socket.emitWithAck instead of socket.emit)

https://socket.io/docs/v4/tutorial/api-overview#with-a-promise

Otherwise everything is async and response will be null when you check for it.

Thank you